# Running Eclipse plugin-tests with JMockit and JUnit 3

Tags: unit-testing, junit, eclipse-plugin, jmockit

I try to run plugin-tests (not regular unit-tests) in Eclispe Helios with JMockit. Unfortunately the Mocking does not work. I get

> WARNING: JMockit was initialized on demand, which may cause certain tests to fail;
>   please check the documentation for better ways to get it initialized.

and bytecode-instrumentation fails with an exception. 
I added "-javaagent:mockit.jar" to the VM-arguments in the plugin-test launcher. This doesn't help.
What can I do to get JMockit to run?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the standard Eclipse JUnit library from your build path.

If you are using maven, add JUnit as a dependency listed after JMockit in the pom. If you are not using maven, add your junit.jar to your libaries after the jmockit jar.

You only need the javaagent argument in the launcher if you are using Java 1.5. Java 1.6 can do without it.